# Enum Can not be serialized in Asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am dealing with a reference service in ASP.net Web API , when I call one of its function and fill all the required arguments I face this unusual error. The current .NET Framework of my project is 4.5.2, despite nothing happened when it was downgraded to 3.5.

You can cheer me up, if you can give me some points to tackle the problem.

Here is the error I get:

> Enum value '0' is invalid for type
> 'WebApplication8.ServiceReference1.InsuranceCompanyEnum' and cannot be
> serialized. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are
> marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has
> DataContractAttribute attribute

Here is the code

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="InsuranceCompanyEnum", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGS.TRN.Common.Entities")]
public enum InsuranceCompanyEnum : int {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Iran = 2,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Asia = 4,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Dana = 5,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Moealem = 6,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Alborz = 7,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_KarAfarin = 8,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Parsian = 9,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Toseeh = 10,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Sina = 11,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Saman = 12,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Rzai = 13,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Novin = 14,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Dey = 15,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Mihan = 16,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Mellat = 17,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Hafez = 18,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Etekayi_Amin = 19,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Iran_Moein = 20,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Omid = 21,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Pasargad = 23,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Etekayi_Iranian = 25,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Kosar = 26,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Teavon = 32,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Ma = 33,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Asmari = 34,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Sarmad = 35,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Arman = 36,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Faghed_Bimeh = 38,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Tejarat_No = 39,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Motaghabel_Etminan_Motahed_Gheshm = 40,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Motaghabel_Kish = 41,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Sherkathaye_Edghami_Dana = 42,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Etekayi_Bimeh_Markazi_IRR = 43,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Hesab_Etekayi_Vijeh = 44,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Hekmat_Saba = 45,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Zendagi_Khavarmiyaneh = 46,
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bimeh_Zendagi_Baran = 47,
}




WebApplication8.ServiceReference1.InquiryResponse InsertBillOfLading(WebApplication8.ServiceReference1.BillOfLading BillOfLading); 
    
public partial class BillOfLading 
{ 
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()] 
    private WebApplication13.ServiceReference1.InsuranceCompanyEnum InsuranceCompanyField;
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public WebApplication8.ServiceReference1.InsuranceCompanyEnum InsuranceCompany {
        get {
            return this.InsuranceCompanyField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.InsuranceCompanyField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.InsuranceCompanyField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("InsuranceCompany");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I have been sending to the server is:

```
ServiceReference1.BillOfLading bill = new ServiceReference1.BillOfLading();
bill.InsuranceCompany = (ServiceReference1.InsuranceCompanyEnum)4;          
var result = srv.InsertBillOfLading(bill);
```

Comment: As a workaround you can return int in place of enum values

Comment: What are the values of the fields sent to server? Does it exists between the values of the enum?  Which .net version are you using?

Comment: There is no enum defined with value = 0

Comment: @MDZand I just mentioned the values which send to the server, but as you can see the value that I used is exists beyond the enum. The project has been using .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: @KjartanValurÞórðarson You are right, is not defined but what I have been sending to the server is not the value of 0. take a look at my sending code, please

Comment: @viveknuna I can not return the type of int, because of it is not matched with the server's schema.  Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGS.TRN.Common.Entities")]